# Web Applications Switching Browsers

Tags: browser, internet-explorer-11, microsoft-edge

At my company we all got upgraded this year to Windows 10. We have Microsoft Edge and Internet Explorer 11 installed.  I have set my default browser to Edge, but I notice that sometimes I will click on a company link that is forwarded to me, and while it initially starts to open in the Edge Browser, Internet Explorer will then open up the link instead.  How does this work?  Are there meta tags or something that control what browser is supposed to open? Can I add these tags to my own intranet web applications? Can I reverse direction, and always open up a link in Edge, even if Internet Explorer is the default browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this is happens due to **Enterprise mode** in Windows 10 OS.

This action occurs without any user input. For example, Contoso Travel requires Internet Explorer legacy proprietary technologies. The website was on the **Enterprise Mode site list or in the Intranet Zone**. When a user visit the following page in Microsoft Edge, the site is automatically opened in Internet Explorer 11.

References:

(1) [How Enterprise Mode works in Windows 10](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4019877/windows-10-open-internet-explorer-11-for-webpages-that-required-enterp)

(2) [Enterprise Mode and the Enterprise Mode Site List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/internet-explorer/ie11-deploy-guide/what-is-enterprise-mode)

(3) [Turn on Enterprise Mode and use a site list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/internet-explorer/ie11-deploy-guide/turn-on-enterprise-mode-and-use-a-site-list)

(4) [Use the Enterprise Mode Site List Manager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/internet-explorer/ie11-deploy-guide/use-the-enterprise-mode-site-list-manager)

Comment: Thanks - this was very helpful.